# ROC-AUC score of 1 when there are no TP and FPs

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to calculate metrics and ROC-AUC scores based on the following inputs df1 and roc_input.
The code below works fine when there are some values in all four metric types but if some of the metrics have zero, I run into either a zero-division problem or ROC-AUC score of 1. How should I resolve this?

df1

```
TP= 0
FN= 673
TN= 826
FP= 0
```

code

```
    def metrics(self, tp, fp, tn, fn):
        sensitivity = tp / (tp+fn),
        specificity = tn / (tn+fp),
        precision = tp / (tp+fp),
        recall = tn / (tn+fn),
        return sensitivity, specificity, precision, recall
```

roc_input

[link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gireeshkbogu/099151da1db1fce47b190196892d83b6/raw/46ef7af941cc429e235ddf13377ec344e3c20cbe/file.csv) to download data

code

```
    def roc_plot(self, roc_input):
        n_classes = 2
        y_test = np.array(roc_input['y_test'], dtype=int)
        y_score = np.array(roc_input['y_score'], dtype=int)
        plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
        fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_score)
        auc1 = auc(fpr,tpr)
        plt.plot(fpr, tpr,label='AUC = %0.2f)' % auc1, color='red', linewidth=2)
        plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--', lw=1)
        plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
        plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
        plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')  
        plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate') 
        plt.title(myphd_id) 
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.legend(loc="lower right")
        plt.tight_layout()
        return auc1
```

Comment: What sort of resolution are you looking for? If tp+fp is zero and you divide by tp+fp you'll have a division by zero error. And AUC will be meaningless. It looks like the problem is either in your sampling or your data. How did you end up with a dataset with no positive cases in it?

Comment: I have some cases where I am not supposed to have any positive predictions and this is one of that. I want to print Sn/ Sp/P/R as zeroes instead of running into an error and also AUC as zero. With the above code, I get an AUC of 1 strangely.

Comment: If you just want to print out a zero, do something like if (tp+fp == 0): print(whatever you wanna print). Though why do you want 0? The correct value isn't 0 and printing 0 would be possibly misleading. That AUC is one instead of zero here is just a design decision. You can print whatever you like, of course.

Comment: But I strongly suspect you have a conceptual misunderstanding somewhere. If you know that all the rows in a dataset have negative label, then what is the point of running a predictive model on them? What you have is a model that always predicts the negative case, which just isn't a very good model. Without showing us the code you used to train the model, we can't help figure out why that happens.

Comment: I should print NA's instead of zeroes in that case? The last comment is to show that those datasets have a negative label and the model didn't work. I need this to evaluate how many datasets are good enough to calculate the ROC score. The aim is not to have a perfect score but to whether it is possible to calculate it or not. Does it make sense?

Comment: If something is not defined (like division by zero) if you print zero then you're printing incorrect information. So I'd recommend against that.

Comment: What about auc score? is it possible to have an auc score of 1 when there are no tp and fp?